# Can OrderedFriendsListInitialData Be Accesed Via API

Tags: facebook, web-scraping

Hi I'm a web developer and a client has asked me if I can build an app that displays the information contained inside the **OrderedFriendsListInitialData**. This information is found when you view the source code on your Facebook news feed.

The Facebook Terms of Service is very clear about NOT scraping Facebook pages, so I would need to access the data via the API. The idea is to allow users to see this list in a convenient way though a Facebook app.

**Also**, if this is NOT possible, then would Facebook make an exception to scraping this singular element for the sole purpose of displaying it to the user it was generated for.

I.e. not showing it to other people, only scraping the data to show it directly to the user without saving it to any database.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API available to return the coefficient-ranked friends list - if your app needs to organise friends based on the user's relationship to the friends, a popular method to do this is to examine the user's photo tags and/or news feed and likes to choose friends most closely associated with the user